# What does the intensity in an MR image represent?

Tags: mri, medical-imaging

[Hounsfield units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hounsfield_scale) are frequently used as intensity for CT images.

What is used for MR images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no units for MRI intensity.

[A Comparison of Five Methods for Signal Intensity Standardization in MRI (CEUR-WS.org)](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-347/p036.pdf):

> A major problem in magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) is the lack of a
>   pulse sequence dependent standardized intensity scale like the
>   Hounsfield units in computed tomography.

[MRI sequences (Radiopedia)](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/mri-sequences-overview):

> When describing most MRI sequences we refer to the shade of grey of
>   tissues or fluid with the word intensity, leading to the following
>   absolute terms:
>
> - high signal intensity = white
> - intermediate signal intensity = grey
> - low signal intensity = black
>
> Often we refer to the appearance by relative terms:
>
> - hyperintense = brighter than the thing we are comparing it to
> - isointense = same brightness as the thing we are comparing it to
> - hypointense = darker than the thing we are comparing it to
>
> *Annoyingly these relative terms are used without reference to the tissue being used as the comparison.*

See also: [Signal intensity (MR-tip.com)](https://www.mr-tip.com/serv1.php?type=db1&dbs=Signal%20Intensity)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!